# GoLang wrapper for EWS / ExchangeService

Tags: c#, go, dll, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have some C# code that uses the ExchangeService (via Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll) object to do some typical email tasks (e.g. fetch email, send email). I'd like to be able to do the same thing, but using Go instead of C#. What is the most direct way to do this? I understand there are tools such as CGo but given that this is MSFT-provided DLL that is part of the .NET framework, I suspect the process is not as simple as it would be if I were creating my own DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the managed .dll with a .NET language, i.e., C#, PowerShell, etc. If you are not going to use a .NET language then you have to construct your own SOAP requests for EWS to consume.

FYI, if this is an Exchange 2016 environment you might want to look into the Exchange REST API which is language agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

You have to roll your own SOAP requests to EWS. The managed/.NET EWS API is just a nicely packaged set of SOAP requests.

Comment: Part of the reason to use the DLL in the first place is to use its support for communicating with the server using EAS. Can a SOAP approach achieve the same thing? If not I will clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on https://github.com/mhewedy/ews can be a good start.